# Python3 Tkinter I want to make screen transition framework

Tags: python3

I want to make screen transition framework.

Please tell me the best way.

Conditions

- Use `tkraise()` method.
- Fast process during screen transitions is performed in main thread. (ex. tkinter(gui), change variable)
- Processing that takes time during screen transitions is performed on the sub thread. (ex. control for databases, files)
- Don't tkinter process in sub thread. Polling between threads is done using a queue.
- File hierarchy is below. Create a file for each screen.

```
Multi threads ex

Frame1
↓
↓ Raise waiting frame: main thread
↓ Data get from database: sub thread
↓ Set data Label and Treeview: main thread
↓ Raise control frame: main thread
↓
Frame2
```

```
File hierarchy

app\
 ├ gui\
    ├ frames.py ･･･ This file is define frame1, frame2, ･･･, frameN.
    ├ frame1.py
    ├ frame2.py
    ･･･
    └ frameN.py
 ├ db\ 
    ├ (Omit)
 └ main.py
```

I made this sample code.

Screen transition and multi threads.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def on_button1():
    frame2.tkraise()


def on_button2():
    frame1.tkraise()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    frame1 = ttk.Frame(root)
    frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    frame2 = ttk.Frame(root)
    frame2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

    button1 = ttk.Button(frame1, text='To frame2', command=on_button1)
    button1.pack()

    button2 = ttk.Button(frame2, text='To frame1', command=on_button2)
    button2.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

```
import queue
import threading
import time
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import ttk


def on_button():
    button['state'] = tk.DISABLED
    thread = threading.Thread(target=ctrl_db)
    thread.start()


def ctrl_db():
    # Long process. (omit)
    time.sleep(3)

    # Don't tkinter process in sub thread.
    def func():
        svar.set(datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d (%a) %H:%M:%S'))
        button['state'] = tk.NORMAL

    # Request tkinter process to main thread.
    queue.put([func,])


def polling():
    # Process the received tkinter process.
    while not queue.empty():
        func, *args = queue.get()
        func(*args)

    root.after(1000, polling)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = queue.Queue()

    root = tk.Tk()

    button = ttk.Button(root, text='Button', command=on_button)
    button.pack()

    svar = tk.StringVar()
    label = ttk.Label(root, textvariable=svar)
    label.pack()

    root.after(1000, polling)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Programming questions are off topic here and belong on [so].